# How does one share assets across Jest Tests

Tags: jestjs

How do I set up shared assets across test files?

For example, I have several variables, defined objects, that several tests should use. I also have many `jest.mock()` to also share across the bunch.

I tried an `import` of a class or something but nothing happens. To be fair, not sure what type of object I should create: class, function, unicorn, etc.?

I looked into creating my own `TestEnvironment` but can't see how this gets referenced by my tests. Everything I've seen says it just works. LIES!

This is a React app, latest versions of React and Jest, using `create-react-app`.

Answer (score 2):

> For example, I have several variables, defined objects, that several tests should use.

We are using normal ES6 imports for that. Also it makes sense to try to avoid tight coulping for test suites.

> I also have many jest.mock() to also share across the bunch.

You can use [manual mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks) feature for that. Manual mocks are defined by writing a module in a **mocks**/ subdirectory immediately adjacent to the module.

> To be fair, not sure what type of object I should create: class, function, unicorn, etc.?

Mock should be the same type and have the same interface as mocked entity.

Comment: Yes, but, at least as far as the docs tells us, that's only helpful if you wish to mock a single default export and always use the same mock.  This is normal when mocking a library but it's not very helpful when you wish to mock your own code with named exports (often you'll wish to use different mocks in different tests).